# Fingerprint database for neural network project

Tags: neural-network

I need a fingerprint database for my neural network project. I am not able to find it online. Can someone please help me find it?

Answer (score 0):

Here there are several fingerprint databases you can download for free:

http://biometrics.idealtest.org/dbDetailForUser.do?id=7